# Terraform count

Tags: azure, terraform

Im using count to define whether the resource is created or not, but i was planning to use the same count to multiply the same resource once it needed without repeating the code. is it possible and how could i do that ?

Thanks in advance

```
  resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "vm_datadisk" {
   count = var.create_datadisk ? 1 : 0 
   name                 = "${var.vm_name}-datadisk"
   location             = azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.location
   resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.vm_rg.name
   storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
   create_option        = "Empty"
   disk_size_gb         = "0"
  }
  resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "vm_datadisk_attach" {
   count = var.create_datadisk ? 1 : 0
   managed_disk_id = element(azurerm_managed_disk.vm_datadisk.*.id,count.index)
   virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm_config.id
   lun                = "0"
   caching            = "ReadWrite"
  }
```

Comment: Please summarize your question properly in the title. "Terraform count" is about as generic as possible and does not help other people experiencing your specific issue with it. A possibility would be: "How do I get make multiple copies of a conditional resource?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, that would be as easy, as increasing count above `1` and using [count.index](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#count-index) in the resource name.

Example:

```
  resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "vm_datadisk" {
   count = var.datadisk_count
   name  = "${var.vm_name}-datadisk-${count.index}"
   ...
  }

  resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "vm_datadisk_attach" {
   count = var.datadisk_count
   managed_disk_id = azurerm_managed_disk.vm_datadisk[*].id[count.index]
   ...
  }
```

Comment: Hi beatcracker, thanks for your support that was exactly what a needed !

Comment: user3573246, you should accept this answer to reward beatcracker properly for the effort in answering it.

Comment: its done, my mistake i forgot !! thanks  again beatcracker